# What is an example of a nonconstant subharmonic function that attains a minimum?

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, harmonic-functions

Let $D$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}$.

What would be an example of a nonconstant subharmonic function that attains its minimum in the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any $z_0\in D$. Let $f(z) = |z - z_0|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

What examples of subharmonic functions do you know?  What have you tried?  The easiest thing would be to find a rotation invariant function which is subharmonic, and increasing along the real line.  You should be able to produce many such functions